# Listview setOnItemClickListener crashed when i open new activity on item click

Tags: android

This is my code where i set listview item click listener.

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {


                    Intent it=new Intent(ProfileView.this,View_profile.class);

                    it.putExtra("position", position);






                    startActivity(it);              

                }
            });
```

And this is Another Activity that i want to open after click of listview item.
that is the code inside of (View_profile Activity).

public class View_profile extends ActionBarActivity implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener {

```
 private SliderLayout mDemoSlider;
 String value="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_profile);



       // int prePosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);
       // System.out.println(""+prePosition);

        Intent i=getIntent();
        value=i.getStringExtra("position");
        System.out.println(""+value);

        mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider_view);

        HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        url_maps.put("Hannibal", "http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/hannibal-season-2-release-date.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Big Bang Theory", "http://tvfiles.alphacoders.com/100/hdclearart-10.png");
        url_maps.put("House of Cards", "http://cdn3.nflximg.net/images/3093/2043093.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Game of Thrones", "http://images.boomsbeat.com/data/images/full/19640/game-of-thrones-season-4-jpg.jpg");

        HashMap<String,Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        file_maps.put("Hannibal",R.drawable.hannibal);
        file_maps.put("Big Bang Theory",R.drawable.bigbang);
        file_maps.put("House of Cards",R.drawable.house);
        file_maps.put("Game of Thrones", R.drawable.game_of_thrones);

        for(String name : file_maps.keySet()){
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(file_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

            //add your extra information
            textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra",name);

           mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
        }
        mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
        mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);
        ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.transformers);
        l.setAdapter(new TransformerAdapter(this));
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(((TextView) view).getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(View_profile.this, ((TextView) view).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

@Override
public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: update your logcat in the question

Comment: Please provide the stack trace

Comment: have you registered View_profile class in manifest

Answer (score 1):

`getStringExtra()` for retrieving int may fail

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                   @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                        Intent it=new Intent(ProfileView.this,View_profile.class);
                        it.putIntExtra("position", position);
                        ProfileView.this.startActivity(it);              
                    }
                });
```

and at receiving end

```
Intent i=getIntent();
value=i.getIntExtra("position");//your passing position as int
```

Comment: nanoweb is using the same code in his question, so problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting NullPointerException somewhere.

Please provide the stack trace, because error could happen either inside setOnItemClickListener or inside the View_profile Activity.